# HTML canvas shapes and HTML string to Visio diagram Files

Tags: c#, html, .net, canvas, visio

Now I am working in VISIO Tools in .NET like converting visio file into Images and PDF like that so one another requirement for now to converting and exporting HTML canvas shapes and HTML string to Visio diagram Files(*.vsd).

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application.dll` to work but I did not found any method to convert HTML to Visio.

Is There any why to Convert these things using Microsoft Library As Office suite...

I've spent couple of days to investigate into `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.dll` to make these things but not getting success now..

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: // load an existing visio diagram
Diagram diagram = new Diagram("Basic Flowchart.vsd");
// save in the local storage
diagram.Save("Output.html", SaveFileFormat.HTML);

// load an existing visio diagram
Diagram diagram = new Diagram("Basic Flowchart.vsd");

// save resultant HTML directly to a stream
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
diagram.Save(stream, SaveFileFormat.HTML);

Comment: This is use for Visio to HTML file...

Comment: I don't understand your question completely. Are you trying to create HTML from a Visio diagram, or a Visio diagram from HTML?

Comment: Visio diagram from HTML @JonFournier